# SemanticImport changes "string" type to "quantity" type--how to change during import or after import?

Tags: import, units, data-types

This question may overlap with other questions about the quirks of SemanticImport, but I don't see this specific wrinkle on StackExchange and I hope it will be a simple answer to help me and others that bump into this.

I import a CSV from a database with SemanticImport, which does a very good job except for one detail: SemanticImport imports a column of string data as a "quantity" type. The entries of this column all start with "Z" followed by four digits. So a string like

```
Z1000
```

becomes

```
1000 Z
```

For clarity, this has the InputForm

```
Quantity[1000, "Zetta"]
```

I need this column to have the "Z####" format of the original CSV. How do I specify this constraint?

1. Do I specify the type during the SemanticImport? or
2. Do I convert the type after import?

I am not fluent at remapping. How do I specify one of the choices above?

Comment: Why not use the second argument for [`SemanticImport`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html)? Compare `SemanticImportString["label1 label2\nZ1000 2"]` with `SemanticImportString["label1 label2\nZ1000 2", {"String", "Number"}]`

Comment: @jason-b I can type the column correctly if I say `dataset[<|"Z column"->"String"|>]`. This code imports this column correctly, but alone. I see that I can import additional columns by specifying type "automatic". The data table has quite a few columns, and I anticipate this problem could arise in future tables. I have never used associations before, so I am weak at extrapolating the syntax. How can I force type only this column, but still import the rest as-is; or how do I force type after this import? I tried a few ideas, but I'm stumbling pretty blind.

Comment: I think the association syntax is for only importing certain columns, I agree it would be convenient to specify the type for only a certain column by name but looking at the documentation I don't know how possible it is.  You might be better off making a replacement rule like ```SemanticImportString["label1 label2\nZ1000 2"] /. 
 Quantity[n_Integer, "Zetta"] :> 
  StringJoin["Z", IntegerString[n, 10, 4]]```